# Add a selectbox to a view

Tags: 7, views

i have a page built with views and i want to add a selectbox to top of the page.

The reason i do that is simply;

1. first, i create options for that selectbox; type-1 / type-2 / type-3  (how and where?)
2. after that, i add that value (for example type-2) to wrapper as a class
3. finally, i write some css and change appearance of the page.

only admins can control that selectbox and change the appearance of the page instantly.

please some help, thank you all.

Comment: What is the function of the select box.

Comment: @Brady i will use that for give to the page a wrapper class.. i change the apperance of the page in that way.. i have a daily page with built in views and i dont want to look all the pages looks same.. i dont know how/where to arrange that selectbox

Comment: What is your competency with writing PHP?

Comment: Do you have Panels installed?

Comment: @Brady i am not expert but i can write php. Panels not installed. I prefer not to use panels but if i must i can used it.

Comment: Doing this without writing code is possible but it's hard. Panels would allow you to do this without writing code. If you don't want panels then you will need to write custom code to do this.

Comment: can you help me to writing this code? or could you explain how can i do this with panels. I prefer coding but i dont want to take your time a lot